# Python Pandas: Store multiple time series of variable length for multiple attributes for multiple users

Tags: python, pandas, storage, dataframe, multi-index

I have been performing an experiment where multiple survey participants have listened to multiple pieces of music using wearable technology to track multiple pieces of information, two examples are `BPM` (Heart-Rate) and `T` (Body temperature).

The goal is to measure the affect of each piece of music (characterised by user feedback) on human emotion.

At the moment all of the data has been stored into `.txt` files (Each line in a text file has an entry) in multiple directories that have the following structure:

```
/user_1
    /BPM
        song_1.txt
           76
           78
        song_2.txt
           76
           78
           85
    /T
        song_1.txt
           35.7
           35.3
           35.3
           35.3
           35.3
        song_2.txt
           32.2
           32.4
           37.8
           32.4
           37.8
```

Every single `.txt` file can have a different length, due to variables such as song length and the inconsistency in time period for the wearable device transmitting. For example, even for the same song, time seris for `BPM` and `T` can be different lengths.

I have already written Python code to traverse and read the values from all of the files.

At the moment, I am considering creating a DataFrame like the following:

```
User_ID Song_ID BPM       T
1       1       [65,...]  [36,...]
1       2       [65,...]  [36,...]
2       1       [65,...]  [36,...]
2       2       [65,...]  [36,...]
```

But I am worried storing an array in each cell could make tasks like standardising the data difficult - I am now wondering if there is a better way to take advantage of MultiIndex to store this in Pandas?

Comment: Have you looked at the library `xarray`? It is designed for scientific data analysis, and extends Pandas to multidimensional arrays.

Comment: The library looks good, any more advice you can given on this specific use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it'll be easier to work with dicts of dataframes. Having lists in cells demand quite a lot of extra effort, which can be avoided in your case.

I guess that the most helpful datastructure for your case would be to have one *DataFrame* for each **song_id**. Even though the data you have for each user will be slightly different, you can still work around by having some *NaN*s. 
Your data is a TimeSeries, so you should have Time as your axis. Most likely you won't want to have the exact time, but the number of seconds since the song started.

Example structure :

```
TimeStamp BPM_user1 BPM_user2
1       65      34
2       64      35
3       66      39
4       69      40
```

Alternatively, you could use a multi column index (having the *Metric* at level 0, and the *userid* at level 1)

Example :

```
          BPM         T
TimeStamp user1 user2 user1 user2
1       65      80     34     38
2       64      78     35     37
3       66      77     39     37
4       69      76     40     37
```

If you have many metrics specific transformations, that second approach is better

Then you'd use a `dict` to hold all your dataframes :

```
df_dict = {
     'song1': read_df(song_id=1),
     'song2': read_df(song_id=2),
}
```

Which you can then iterate easily to performa your analysis :

```
for songid, df in df_dict.items():
       *do analysis*
```

This worklfow is generally easier and less error prone than using pd.Panel